# php - can't find/replace multi line string

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a block of text and replace it with a modified block of text and for some reason it's not working. I can execute the following line in my phpDesigner editor and it works perfectly, but when I try to execute the same command on my linux webserver it doesn't work.

Can someone help me out with a solution whether it's via regex or some other method?

```
    $tmp_code = str_replace('<!--
    {if="$membership.field_files"}
    <li><a href="/Members/Listings.html?id={$listing.id}&action=files"><span>Files</span></a></li>
    {else}
    <li><a href="/Members/Listings.html?id={$listing.id}&action=files"><span>Files</span></a></li>
    {/if}
    -->','{if="$membership.field_files"}
    <li><a href="/Members/Listings.html?id={$listing.id}&action=files"><span>Add/Remove Offers, Products and Files</span></a></li>
    {else}
    <li><a href="/Members/Listings.html?id={$listing.id}&action=files"><span>Add/Remove Offers, Products and Files</span></a></li>
    {/if}',$tmp_code);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is more than likely line endings (i.e. your machine vs *nix).

Your editor should have an option for saving files using a particular line ending. I suggest making it the same as your production environment (i.e. *nix)

Comment: I think you are correct, did some trial/error with some regex and this worked: /((<!--)(\r|\n)(\s+)({if=")(.+)({\/if})(\r|\n)(\s+)(-->))/sm

Answer (score 0):

Try substitution of "\n" for newlines in your search string. Make sure to use the double quotes as single quotes won't interpret some escape sequences for special characters.

Sources:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with the white space (new lines and tabs). You could:

```
$tmp_code = preg_replace('<!--\s*{if="$membership.field_files"}\s*<li><a href="/Members/Listings.html?id={$listing.id}&action=files"><span>Files</span></a></li>\s*{else}\s* <li><a href="/Members/Listings.html?id={$listing.id}&action=files"><span>Files</span></a></li>\s*{/if}\s*-->','{if="$membership.field_files"}
    <li><a href="/Members/Listings.html?id={$listing.id}&action=files"><span>Add/Remove Offers, Products and Files</span></a></li>
    {else}
    <li><a href="/Members/Listings.html?id={$listing.id}&action=files"><span>Add/Remove Offers, Products and Files</span></a></li>
    {/if}',$tmp_code);
```

Which uses \s* to search for any amount of whitespace between lines, instead of the exact amount you type.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get around this problem by setting the internal option setting for `PCRE_DOTALL` using the "`s`" in the pattern string.

Example:

```
$pattern = '# ...pattern goes here... #s';
```

Any dot (period) character inside that pattern will match anything including new lines. By default it does not include new lines.

Reference: [PCRE Pattern Modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)